# Check if package.json has script with a certain name in shell script without using extra NPM packages

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, npm, package.json

I am testing a larger library of NPM packages, that consists of private packages, altered forks of public packages or downstreams of public packages.

```
lib
  |-package_1
  |-package_2
  |-package_N
```

So I am running a shell script through my package lib, that runs in each directory the `npm test` command.

```bash
for D in *; do
    if [ -d "${D}" ]; then
        echo "================================="
        echo "${D}"   # PRINT DIRECTORY NAME
        echo "================================="

        cd $D
        npm run tests
        cd ../  # LEAVE PACKAGE DIR
    fi
done
```

Unfortunately there is not a unique pattern for naming the tests-script in the package's JSON files. Some package are running under `test` a script with **watch-mode** and have a different name for their cli script (mostly named `testcli`).

What I would like to do is something like the following pseudocode:

```bash
if has-testcli-script then
    npm run testcli
else
    npm run test
```

I assume for now, that only those two options exist. I am rather interested in the way of knowing if the script exists, without installing an additional global NPM package.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since npm version 2.11.4 at least, calling `npm run` with no arguments will list all runable scripts. Using that you can check to see if your script is present. So something like:

```
has_testcli_script () {
  [[ $(npm run | grep "^  testcli" | wc -l) > 0 ]]
}

if has_testcli_script; then
  npm run testcli
else
  npm test
fi
```

Or alternatively, just check to see if your script is in the package.json file directly:

```
has_testcli_script () {
  [[ $(cat package.json | grep "^    \"testcli\":" | wc -l) > 0 ]]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case that approach didn't work and I had to implement something using jq instead.

```sh
has_script (script) {
  [[ ! -z "$(jq -rc --arg key $script '.scripts | to_entries | .[] | select(.key == \$key)' package.json)" ]]
}
```

then use it as:

```
if has_script('testcli'); then
 // Do something
else
// Do nothing
fi
```